# day month and year time stamps from gps wrong

Tags: android, time, gps

I'm trying to get the time stamp from the GPS.

I'm using the method onLocationChanged and the Date class like this:

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
        Log.d("TIME","day "+Calendar.get);
        Log.d("TIME","month "+date.getMonth());
        Log.d("TIME","year "+date.getYear());
        Log.d("TIME","hour "+date.getHours());
        Log.d("TIME","minutes "+date.getMinutes());
        Log.d("TIME","seconds "+date.getSeconds());
    }
```

now I know that these methods are deprecated but it's still suppose to give me accurate results right?

the min,sec and hour are fine but :

The day value is 1.

The month value is 1.

The year value is 115 .

How can I know if the problem is with the time I get from location or is it the Date class that's messing things up?

Answer (score 0):

I think the year value are 115 because 2015 is 115 years after 1900.
There are probably some similar explanation for the other values.

Use SimpleDateFormater to format the time.

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String strTime = format.format(loc.getTime());